# Laravel generate migrations from database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a database for my application. I like to generate migrations from this existing table. I tried to make this with [this](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) generator, but this not helped to me. For initial state of database this is OK, create great migrations with indexes and foreign key, but my problem is How to create new migration file when I change some column, but the data must be stay in table.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post examples of what you have tried.

Comment: It sounds like you expect Laravel to reflect changes you make in your database. You need to write these changes into migration files and run them to make changes, rather than make changes and assume something can work out what you've changed. Write your migrations to change your database, not change your database to make your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have already a table with column with foreign key reference, you need to change that column, you have to drop foreign key and then change the column after that add foreign key for that column.